# Canon EOS 2000D shutter counter

Tags: canon, shutter-actuations

Does anyone know of a program to obtain shutter count for a  Canon EOS 2000D  (Rebel T7)? Many other applications were already used with no results.

Comment: Did you try the programm "Exif-Viewer"?

Comment: Try "eosmsg"  http://www.eosmsg.com/

Comment: @Horitsu could you link me to the aforementioned "exif-viewer"?     thanks in advance

Comment: it can be found on google and is exactly called like this.

Comment: Canon cameras do not include a shutter count field in EXIF data, so EXIF based methods do not reveal shutter counts of Canon EOS cameras.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac/Linux, you can try `gphoto2`:

```
gphoto2 --get-config /main/status/shuttercounter
```

To install on Mac, you can try [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). I am not a Mac user, so cannot provide assistance beyond providing the links.

For Linux, use the package manager to install.

Comment: I own a Rebel T7, and can confirm that gphoto2 was able to read the shutter count from my camera.

Answer (score 0):

2nd Gen Canon cameras such as the EOS 2000D don't include shutter counts in EXIF data or in the utility interface (I've been through it back to front, top to bottom, even shook it and nothing fell out of some hidden pocket somewhere). There is an undocumented feature that is accessible through shop service software only obtainable through Canon and only if you're a certified Canon service engineer, so really your only hope is to find one of those or get certified.

Answer (score -3):

There is a alternative way to find your camera shutter count without installing any firmware. Visit this [Website](https://www.camerashuttercount.com) and upload the last photo that you taken from your camera. You will get the results.

Comment: This can't work.

Comment: This worked for my NikonD5300 and Canon 600D

Comment: Yes, but see the other answers and comments. The files from this camera do not contain the needed information.