# Did Canon remove the possibility to read the shuttercount?

Tags: canon, software, shutter

So, I just saw [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/104712/canon-eos-2000d-shutter-counter) question and it got me thinking of something I stumbled upon recently.

Whenever I get a Canon camera in my hands, I read out its shuttercount using `gphoto2` on Linux. What I do is basically run the following command:

```
gphoto2 --get-config /main/status/shuttercounter
```

And that works for a lot of, especially older, Canon cameras.
Now recently I got hands on a 750D and a 760D, and neither have this property. And this gets me thinking, is this really a software issue? As in, the software we use to read.

Because both of those cameras connect just fine to `gphoto2`, and when I run `gphoto2 --list-config` I get a HUGE list with all kinds of configuration entires that I can read out, but no `shuttercounter` property there.

So this leaves me wondering, did Canon simply drop this property? I don't really see why `gphoto2` would support those cameras and a ton of properties, except for the `shuttercounter`. To me this sounds more like those cameras simply don't come with it. But then again I constantly see people on the internet asking makers of software like this to "update to support my camera when?", and nobody ever seems to tell them "Never.". Does anyone know more?

Could we ever read out the shuttercount of those devices? What would it take?

**Edit:** [Here](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php) is a list of cameras supported by `gphoto2`. Both 750D and 760D are there.

Comment: I don't have a Canon to check, but have you tried exiftool & just spit out the full exif, read it manually to see if it's there but in a different guise?

Comment: @Tetsujin Holy s**t. I've used `exiv2` in the past but now tried the `exiftool` you mentioned and it reads like hundreds of stuff off an image. However, all I see (tested on a 70D which does have the shuttercount property) is the `Image Number` and `File Index`, which is not the shuttercount, but the current image number (since last reset).

Comment: Yeah, it has more info than you're ever likely to need ;) I've got nothing I can compare with except my Nikon, which does show as Shutter Count : 17565

Comment: Are you using the very latest version of gphoto2? Also, most (if not all) Canon cameras do not write their shutter count into EXIF.

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62381/how-do-i-determine-the-shutter-count-on-a-eos-60d-body

Comment: @flolilolilo Yes, latest version of all tools. Like I said, I can control a 760D or 750D without any problem and I can read a TON off of it. Just no shuttercount property there and honestly I doubt it has anything to do with the software. On a 60D I can read it out with gphoto2 without any issues. There is no magic lantern for the 750D/760D yet.

Comment: Why should it not have to do with it? The 60D used a DIGIC 4, the 760D a DIGIC 6 processor. As said, Caon has never written the shuttercount in the exif data...well, at least not for as long as i can remember.

Comment: @flolilolilo Because the 750D/760D has full support in control, data transfer and configuration read/write using `gphoto2`. Why should everything be supported and there exactly for the shuttercount? For other cameras, it is accessible through the main configuration tree. I can access that tree on a 750D/760D using `ghoto2` too, just the shuttercounter property isn't there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the shutter count on a EOS 60D body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62381/how-do-i-determine-the-shutter-count-on-a-eos-60d-body)